# numpy can't transpose row vector into column?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector, transpose

numpy seems not to be able to transpose a vector? 
I was wanting to project a vector into a matrix which you can do for rows no problem using np.tile -

```
In [7]: vector = np.arange(start=0,stop=1,step=1.0/5)
In [8]: mat = np.tile(vector, (2,1))   
In [9]: mat
Out[9]: array([[ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8],
               [ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8]])
```

but if you want to tile the same vector as a  column it seems you have to do

```
In[11]: mat = np.tile(vector,(2,1))
In[12]: mat=mat.transpose()
In[13]: mat
Out[13]: array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
                 [ 0.2,  0.2],
                 [ 0.4,  0.4],
                 [ 0.6,  0.6],
                 [ 0.8,  0.8]])
```

instead of the more logical (to me anyway)

```
In[30]: mat = np.tile(vector.transpose(),(1,2))
```

which doesnt give the desired result, instead giving a row vector, with transpose being irrelevant -

```
Out[31]: array([[ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8]])
```

while this isnt a big problem I am concerned about the injustice of it

Comment: Transpose switches dimensions.  For a 1d array that means switching the 1st dimension with the 1st dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways of creating an array like this.

`repeat` is faster than `tile`, and `reshape` is nearly costless:

```
In [112]: v=np.arange(0,1,1/5)
In [113]: v
Out[113]: array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8])
In [114]: np.repeat(v,2)
Out[114]: array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0.2,  0.2,  0.4,  0.4,  0.6,  0.6,  0.8,  0.8])
In [115]: np.repeat(v,2).reshape(-1,2)
Out[115]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.2,  0.2],
       [ 0.4,  0.4],
       [ 0.6,  0.6],
       [ 0.8,  0.8]])
```

Or turn `v` into a 'column vector' with `newaxis`:

```
In [118]:  np.repeat(v[:,None],2,axis=1)
Out[118]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.2,  0.2],
       [ 0.4,  0.4],
       [ 0.6,  0.6],
       [ 0.8,  0.8]])

In [119]: v[:,None]+np.zeros(2)
Out[119]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.2,  0.2],
       [ 0.4,  0.4],
       [ 0.6,  0.6],
       [ 0.8,  0.8]])

In [120]: np.column_stack([v]*2)
Out[120]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.2,  0.2],
       [ 0.4,  0.4],
       [ 0.6,  0.6],
       [ 0.8,  0.8]])

In [124]: np.broadcast_to(v[:,None],(v.shape[0],2))
Out[124]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.2,  0.2],
       [ 0.4,  0.4],
       [ 0.6,  0.6],
       [ 0.8,  0.8]])
```

This last one actually does `@piRSquared's` strided trick:

```
In [125]: _.strides
Out[125]: (8, 0)
```

`v[:,None]` could also be produced with `v[None,:].T` (or `v[None].T`)

Answer (score 3):

`transpose` doesn't really do any thing on a 1d array. One alternative is to reshape *vector* to 2d firstly, from which it gets two axis, and then you can use `np.tile` with *reps* parameter specified for each axis:

```
np.tile(vector[:,None], (1,2))
#array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
#       [ 0.2,  0.2],
#       [ 0.4,  0.4],
#       [ 0.6,  0.6],
#       [ 0.8,  0.8]])
```

Comment: @jeremy_rutman: By taking advantage of [NumPy broadcasting](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html#broadcasting) you might be able to just use `vector[:, None]` instead of explicitly tiling with `np.tile(vector[:,None], (1,2))`.

Answer (score 1):

From *project*`/`**kill**

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as strided

strided(vector, (vector.size, 2), (vector.strides[0], 0))

array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.2,  0.2],
       [ 0.4,  0.4],
       [ 0.6,  0.6],
       [ 0.8,  0.8]])
```

__

```
strided(vector, (2, vector.size), (0, vector.strides[0]))

array([[ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8],
       [ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8]])
```